# Firefox can find certificate, but curl cannot (while tunneling https through ssh)

Tags: ssl, curl, firefox, https, certificate

## Background:

I have a running app at ports `8080` in the remote server and a https ingress proxy at `443` on the same server, which redirects everything to `8080` app after handling the SSL.

## What I want to do:

I want to communicate with the app through SSL remotely, while not having access directly to this domain (it is on a local network, I can access the server remotely via a different domain).

## What I did:

I tunneled 443 port from my remote server `ssh -L 3001:0.0.0.0:443 user@example.com`. I then added `127.0.0.1   example.com` to my `/etc/hosts` to make sure that the domain on my system is resolved properly.

Now, what I *can* do is enter `https://example.com:3001/some/thing/` in firefox and it gets me a proper response from the server, while everything is ran through ssl without any problems. I *also* am able to use curl without checking the certificate: `curl --insecure https://example.com:3001/some/thing` works fine.

At the same time secure `curl` call fails: `curl https://example.com:3001/some/thing` with the error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Just to make sure both are using the same certificates, I actually used this tool: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/mk-ca-bundle.html to create a `ca-bundle.crt` from the most recent firefox certificates and passed it to curl with `--cacert ca-bundle.crt`. No luck - the same error. (I also tried following other curl tutorial on getting the local installation of firefox's certs, also no luck).

## Question

**What is going on?** Why is curl's output different from firefox's even if I seem to use the same certificates? How can I debug this?

#### Side note

The real reason I am concerned about it is that with a normal (local) access to the server, I observed the same behaviour: I could connect to the server through chrome on https, but my react native app could not. I suspect the app to use `libcurl` under the hood or something similar and I believe debugging this problem could help me understand what's the problem with the app.

Comment: Maybe there is some incomplete chain in the server configuration, Firefox can often work around this issue while curl cannot. If the site is public check it out with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Comment: Each HTTPS (TLS) client is free to use its own trust store for CAs. Besides that without seeing the certificate it would be hard to answer you... Look at the certificate, its issuer, and the possible intermediate, and look inside the bundle of CAs you use to see what you have exactly.